# Convert presention file (abc.ppt/abc.pptx/abc.odt) in to abc.pdf using linux command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, powerpoint, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a *.ppt file in to *.pdf file using linux command, I am using **libreoffice** for **Ubuntu-12.04** server and it is working fine and the command is following

```
sudo /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export /var/www/...../1234.pptx --outdir /var/www/..../
```

I installed **libreoffice** on different server having **Ubuntu-14.04** but the command is not working, please suggest any solution preferably using libreoffice.

Thanks
Atul

Comment: Any error messages? Is the output dir writable? Result of `ls -lat /usr/bin/libreoffice`?

Comment: Thanks tohuwawohu, for your quick response. 

No i am not getting any error after running the command. 
We provided the output directory 0777 permission for now and the  result of    
 ls -lat /usr/bin/libreoffice
 is   
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Dec  4 18:43 /usr/bin/libreoffice -> ../lib/libreoffice/program/soffice

Comment: Hmm - i can't reproduce this. Does converting as normal user (without `sudo`) work? I noticed that libreoffice uses `impress_pdf_Export` when i execute `--convert-to pdf` (without specifying the output filter name). Is impress able to open the pptx?

Comment: I am using following command not its working.
    sudo /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:impress_pdf_Export /var/www/...../1234.pptx --outdir /var/www/...../